# Linking failed when using Hockey SDK in Xamarin IOS App

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, hockeyapp

I have a Xamarin.forms app. In the iOS project I installed the HockeyApp package from [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HockeySDK.Xamarin/) and followed the samples [here](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/hockeyappios) by adding the following code in my `AppDelegate.cs`:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    //We MUST wrap our setup in this block to wire up
    // Mono's SIGSEGV and SIGBUS signals
    HockeyApp.Setup.EnableCustomCrashReporting (() => {

        //Get the shared instance
        var manager = BITHockeyManager.SharedHockeyManager;

        //Configure it to use our APP_ID
        manager.Configure ("YOUR-HOCKEYAPP-APPID");

        //Start the manager
        manager.StartManager ();

        //Authenticate (there are other authentication options)
        manager.Authenticator.AuthenticateInstallation ();

        //Rethrow any unhandled .NET exceptions as native iOS 
        // exceptions so the stack traces appear nicely in HockeyApp
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (sender, e) => 
            Setup.ThrowExceptionAsNative(e.ExceptionObject);

        TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += (sender, e) => 
            Setup.ThrowExceptionAsNative(e.Exception);
    });

    //The rest of your code here
    // ...
}
```

As soon as I try to compile the program Visual Studio throws the following  error (and some more of that kind):

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Native linking failed, undefined symbol:
>   std::__1::__vector_base_common::__throw_length_error() const.
>   Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced
>   and native libraries are properly linked in.  App.iOS

When I comment that code piece everything runs fine.
Any suggestions on that? Anybody who successfully setup Hockey in an ios xamarin forms project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you targeting iOS 6?

If so from the [getting started section](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/hockeyappios) on the HockeyApp Component it states this:

> Targeting iOS 6.0
>
> If you would like your app to target iOS 6.0 you will need to add the following arguments to your application project settings.
>
> Open project Options
>   Under Build -> iOS Build
>   Go to the Additional Options -> Additional mtouch arguments and add:
>   -cxx ->gcc_flags "-lc++"

Also this [bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=34381) says the same thing

Comment: Thanks man. I read about targeting iOS 6 and about those settings but I did not realize that my app actually targeted iOS 6. I changed it and now it is working...

Comment: No worries, glad I could help.